# Calculating probability based variables?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am going to try and describe this as best I can.

In a risk/reward calculation I have an item with a $65$% gain and a historical likelihood of achieving a $100$% total gain. To reach $100$% would require a $54$% increase in value so in order not to risk a greater ratio than I intend to gain the maximum amount of the $65$% gain I could risk would be $35$% (since a $54$% increase would be required to offset that loss) and I would be risking more than I had potential to gain.

Now in the above example I had a somewhat hard value target, but lets say I was working with probabilities instead of hard target numbers. How would that change the way the risk is calculated since the it is being calculated based off of current value relative to potential final value? In such a scenario there would be a certain chance that the total gain would top out at $75$% or could top out at $150$%. When your dealing with flexible values like that how are probabilities factored in?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expected payoffs are usually computed using some method which is similar to the following:

$E(\pi) = pX + (1 - p)Y$

...where $E(\pi)$ represents the expected payoff, $X$ and $Y$ are the payoffs the only two possible events, and $p$ is the probability of event $X$ occuring ( $1 - p$ is, of course, the probability of $Y$ occuring).

This set-up can be expanded to accomodate as many possible events as you need. It is important to note that $X$ and $Y$ could, but do not need to, represent actual dollar amounts.

Generally, you would assume that your choices about what to invest (or other actions you take) can change $X$ and $Y$, your payoffs under different possible future events, but that you cannot affect $p$, the probabilities of those events ocurring.

Is this the kind of answer you are looking for? If so, I can expand it to include more details.